# Indents & trying to format columns

Tags: two-column, multicol

I have been looking through other forums on how to separate columns of text and the like and I am having trouble getting my text to align up. I would like to have the two names on the same line, but \vspace doesn't do it. Also using 
\setlength{colsep} or the likes, I couldn't seperate the text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!
\
Thanks 
\
James

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{multicol} \\ 
\usepackage{url} \\


 \begin{document}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
 \section{Section}
\subsection*{sub section}

Mr Joe Blogs- Person
\\Level 1 Cordelias Street
\\Australia 
\\Email:\url{Joe Blogsn@the email is long.com}
\\\\
\vspace{1cm}
\columnbreak

\noindent
Jim - Person
\\Level 1 Cordelias Street
\\Australia
\\Email: \url{Joeblogs@.com}
\end{multicols}
\pagebreak
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And if you put `\subsection*{...}` out of `multicols` environment? (precisely above of `multicols`)

Comment: image of your code is not helpful ... please provide a small, complete document, which we can copy to our computers and test then.welcome to tex.se

Comment: Sorry I am new to the whole posting questions thing, thank you for your patience

Comment: I have fixed the headings issue, but separating the text  columns is still not working

Comment: I don't believe the code you've posted compiles for you without error. Also, never use `\\ ` to end a line outside special environments such as `tabular` and `array`.

Comment: Read the console output. Sometimes, it tells you useful stuff. What do you want to do with the too-wide email address?